# Find a generator of a field extension defined by an f-d algebra

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra

Here's my problem:  I have a commutative $n$-dimensional finite algebra over a field $K$, with the elements represented as vectors in $K^n$ and a set of $n$ $nxn$ matrices that define how to multiply by each of the $n$ basis elements.

We know that it's isomorphic to a direct product of fields.  If it's not a field itself, we can compute a primary decomposition and mod out by its maximal ideals to get its constituent fields that way.

So, assuming w.l.o.g. that it's a field, and thus an algebraic extension of $K$ (since it's finite dimensional as a vector space), how can we find a generator of the field extension?

Some ideas that I've thought of:

1. Trial run through all of the elements until we find a generator.
2. Each basis element is the generator of a subfield, but none of them have to generate the entire extension field.  Computing a generator of the entire extension field is the primitive element problem.

   2a. Yokoyama *et al* showed how to use bounds on the absolute values of the embeddings into $\mathbb{C}$ to find a primitive element that generates the entire extension field.
3. Treat the $n$ defining matrices as a (2,1) tensor (see the third sentence in the fourth section of [2]) and try to run some kind of classification algorithm, like in [3]?  Get it into some kind of standard form from which you could read off a generator?

Obvious problems with them:

1. If $K$ is infinite, then I'm not sure how to order the elements to make sure that I eventually get one that works.
2. sounds best at the moment

   2a. Computing embeddings in $\mathbb{C}$ sounds computationally expensive.
3. is just a sketch of a rough idea

Can anybody offer some advice?

---

[1] *Yokoyama, Kazuhiro; Noro, Masayuki; Takeshima, Taku*, [**Computing primitive elements of extension fields**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/S0747-7171(89)80061-6), J. Symb. Comput. 8, No. 6, 553-580 (1989). [ZBL0697.68054](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0697.68054).

[2] *Belitskii, Genrich R.; Sergeichuk, Vladimir V.*, [**Complexity of matrix problems**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/S0024-3795(02)00391-9), Linear Algebra Appl. 361, 203-222 (2003). [ZBL1030.15011](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1030.15011).

[3] *Sergeichuk, Vladimir V.*, [**Canonical matrices for linear matrix problems**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/S0024-3795(00)00150-6), Linear Algebra Appl. 317, No. 1-3, 53-102 (2000). [ZBL0967.15007](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0967.15007).

Comment: The non-generators will be a subvariety of positive codimension, so if $K$ is infinite then almost every element will be a generator.  So you should pick an element $a$ at random, express $\{a^i:0\leq i<n\}$ in terms of your basis, calculate the determinant and observe that it is almost surely nonzero.  Even if $K$ is finite, you should find a generator after testing a small number of randomly chosen elements.